# How to normalize array of images in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, google-colaboratory, normalization, image-classification

I am trying to write a model that can classify between images of cats and dogs. All the code I have written so far works. However, Once I get to normalizing the images in the array and run it, the runtime crashes (I'm using Colaboratory) as all the available Memory gets used.

```
import glob
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
```

```
files_train = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Cats_Dogs/training_set/*.jpg'
files_test = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Cats_Dogs/test_set/*.jpg'
glob.glob(files_train)
glob.glob(files_test)
images_train = np.array([cv2.imread(image) for image in glob.glob(files_train)])
images_test = np.array([cv2.imread(image) for image in glob.glob(files_test)])
```

```
import os
text_train_list = os.listdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Cats_Dogs/training_set')
text_train = [item[0] for item in text_train_list]
text_test_list = os.listdir('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/Cats_Dogs/test_set')
text_test = [item[0] for item in text_test_list]
text_train = np.array(text_train)
text_test = np.array(text_test)
```

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_enc = LabelEncoder()
vec_1 = label_enc.fit_transform(text_train)
vec_2 = label_enc.fit_transform(text_test)

text_train = to_categorical(vec_1)
text_test = to_categorical(vec_2)
```

```
images_train = images_train / 255
images_test = images_test / 255
```

First I tried running it in a local runtime as I have 12GB of RAM on my machine, but it still uses up everything and crashes. I then tried cutting down the number of training images from 8000 to 3000 and simplifying my code yet it still crashes. Finally, after googling, I found that I must normalize each image one at a time. I tried doing so:

```
img_train = np.array([])

for x in images_train:
  img_train[x] = images_train[x] / 255
```

Yet I still crash, what is the best way to do this without setting fire to my computer?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: most computer vision datasets do not fit in memory, let alone a _contiguous chunk_ of memory which is what you're trying to do in `np.array([cv2.imread(image) for image in glob.glob(files_train)])`